# how to modify a 2D numpy array at specific locations without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I have a arrays of rows and columns which should be set to a particular value. Lets consider the following example

```
 a = array([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to modify entries at rows [0,2] and columns [1,2]. This should result in the following array

```
 a = array([[1, 2, 0],
           [4, 5, 0],
           [7, 8, 9]])
```

I did following and it resulted in modifying each sequence of column in every row

```
rows = [0,1]
cols = [2,2]
b=a[numpy.ix_(rows,columns)]
```

It resulted in the following array modifying every column of the specified array

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 0, 0]])
```

Some one could please let me know how to do it?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT: It is to be noted that rows and columns coincidently happend to be sequentia. The actual point is that these could be arbitrary and in any order. if it is rows = [a,b,c] and cols=[n x z] then I want to modify exactly three elements at locations (a,n),(b,x),(c,z).**

Comment: wow it took me FAR too long to find this...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Adding to what others have said, you can modify these elements using fancy indexing as follows:

```
In [39]: rows = [0,1]

In [40]: cols = [2,2]

In [41]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))

In [42]: a[rows,cols] = 0

In [43]: a
Out[43]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

You might want to read the documentation on indexing multidimensional arrays:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

The key point is:

> if the index arrays have a matching shape, and there is an index array
>   for each dimension of the array being indexed, the resultant array has
>   the same shape as the index arrays, and the values correspond to the
>   index set for each position in the index arrays.

Importantly this also allows you to do things like:

```
In [60]: a[rows,cols] = np.array([33,77])

In [61]: a
Out[61]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 33],
       [ 4,  5, 77],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

where you can set each element independently using another array, list or tuple of the same size.

Comment: You are very right. Thanks for pointing to the documentation. It was a bug in program. I knew it but could not work. Your answer is very explanatory.

Comment: whats with that in[x] syntax you've got going on?

Comment: @johnktejik That's just the output from an ipython/jupyter notebook execution cell. Think of it as a line numbered prompt.

Answer (score 3):

one work around: `ndarray.flatten, np.put(), ndarray.reshape`

try `ndarray.flatten(array)`, that way you are dealing with a one dim array which can be manipulated with `numpy.put(array,[indices],[values])`. Then use `ndarray.reshape()` to get to the original dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your description of the "correct" array doesn't match the columns and rows you specify...

To get your "correct" array, you'd do this:

```
a[:2, 2] = 0
```

To modify the second and third columns of the first and third rows, (rows [0,2] and columns [1,2]) you'd do what you're doing... (Your description of modifying rows [0,2] and columns [1,2] is exactly the result you get, right?)

Comment: The point is that I dont want it sequential... The column and row can be arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as a[0,2]=0 and a[1,2]=0. You could also do a[0:2,2]=0. The ':' based range indexing in python is a half-open interval [0,2) which actually range from 0 to 1 (the end point of 2 is not included).