# Select One Element in Each Row of a Numpy Array by Column Indices

Tags: select, numpy

Is there a better way to get the "output_array" from the "input_array" and "select_id" ?

Can we get rid of `range( input_array.shape[0] )` ?

```
>>> input_array = numpy.array( [ [3,14], [12, 5], [75, 50] ] )
>>> select_id = [0, 1, 1]
>>> print input_array
[[ 3 14]
 [12  5]
 [75 50]]

>>> output_array = input_array[  range( input_array.shape[0] ), select_id ]
>>> print output_array
[ 3  5 50]
```

Comment: It's a sick way of doing it, and definitely not better than what you have, but `np.diagonal(input_array[:, select_id])` will also get you `array([ 3,  5, 50])`.

Comment: Aside from using `arange` instead of `range`, the advanced indexing solution in the question is already the best option.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can choose from given array using [`numpy.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) which constructs an array from an index array (in your case `select_id`) and a set of arrays (in your case `input_array`) to choose from. However you may first need to transpose `input_array` to match dimensions. The following shows a small example:

```
In [101]: input_array
Out[101]: 
array([[ 3, 14],
       [12,  5],
       [75, 50]])

In [102]: input_array.shape
Out[102]: (3, 2)

In [103]: select_id
Out[103]: [0, 1, 1]

In [104]: output_array = np.choose(select_id, input_array.T)

In [105]: output_array
Out[105]: array([ 3,  5, 50])
```

Comment: instead of outputting those values, how do we modify them in place?

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761393/how-to-modify-a-2d-numpy-array-at-specific-locations-without-a-loop

Comment: Have to comment this does not work for large arrays, as pointed out below by Nathan. It gives "ValueError: Need at least 1 and at most 32 array objects." Anyone know the reason this method is limited to small arrays?

Answer (score 9):

(because I can't post this as a comment on the accepted answer)

Note that **`numpy.choose` only works if you have 32 or fewer choices** (in this case, the dimension of your array along which you're indexing must be of size 32 or smaller). Additionally, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) for `numpy.choose` says

> To reduce the chance of misinterpretation, even though the following "abuse" is nominally supported, choices should neither be, nor be thought of as, a single array, i.e., the outermost sequence-like container should be either a list or a tuple.

The OP asks:

1. Is there a better way to get the `output_array` from the `input_array` and `select_id`?

   - I would say, the way you originally suggested seems the best out of those presented here. It is easy to understand, scales to large arrays, and is efficient.
2. Can we get rid of `range(input_array.shape[0])`?

   - Yes, as shown by other answers, but the accepted one doesn't work in general so well as what the OP already suggests doing.

Comment: That would've been an extremely long comment ;)

Comment: Ha, when one writes something as an answer, I think it just gets longer. And I then felt obligated to make it "an answer" by directly addressing the OPs questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) is handy.

```
[input_array[enum, item] for enum, item in enumerate(select_id)]
```

Comment: time-saving by in-line loop is always nice. i really need numpy for processing a lot of data though...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[input_array[x,y] for x,y in zip(range(len(input_array[:,0])),select_id)]
```

Comment: i have to do math on a lot of data. so i try to vectorize with numpy.