# NumPy selecting specific column index per row by using a list of indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm struggling to select the specific columns per row of a NumPy matrix.

Suppose I have the following matrix which I would call `X`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

I also have a `list` of column indexes per every row which I would call `Y`:

```
[1, 0, 2]
```

I need to get the values:

```
[2]
[4]
[9]
```

Instead of a `list` with indexes `Y`, I can also produce a matrix with the same shape as `X` where every column is a `bool` / `int` in the range 0-1 value, indicating whether this is the required column.

```
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```

I know this can be done with iterating over the array and selecting the column values I need. However, this will be executed frequently on big arrays of data and that's why it has to run as fast as it can.

**I was thus wondering if there is a better solution?**

Comment: Is the answer better for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17081678/5046896

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you've got a boolean array you can do direct selection based on that like so:

```
>>> a = np.array([True, True, True, False, False])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b[a]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

To go along with your initial example you could do the following:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> b = np.array([[False,True,False],[True,False,False],[False,False,True]])
>>> a[b]
array([2, 4, 9])
```

You can also add in an `arange` and do direct selection on that, though depending on how you're generating your boolean array and what your code looks like YMMV.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> a[np.arange(len(a)), [1,0,2]]
array([2, 4, 9])
```

Comment: +1 for the example using `arange` . This was particularly useful to me for retrieving different blocks from multiple matrices (so basically the 3D case of this example)

Comment: Hi, could you explain why we have to use `arange` instead of `:`? I know your way works and mine doesn't, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: @tamzord because it's a numpy array and not a vanilla python list, so the `:` syntax doesn't work the same way.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, thanks for responding. My understanding, after some reading, is that mixing `:` with advanced indexing means: "for every sub-space along `:`, apply the given advanced indexing". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tamzord explain what you mean by "sub-space"

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I mean the mathematical definition: when you have a n-dimensional space and you fix one coordinate you obtain a sub-space; that is, a (n-1)-dimensional space. The documentation uses that term and I think it is also using the same definition: (ctrl-F "subspace") http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 56):

You can do something like this:

```
In [7]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
   ...: [4, 5, 6],
   ...: [7, 8, 9]])

In [8]: lst = [1, 0, 2]

In [9]: a[np.arange(len(a)), lst]
Out[9]: array([2, 4, 9])
```

More on indexing multi-dimensional arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: struggling to understand why the arange is needed instead of simply ':' or range.

Comment: @MadmanLee Hi, using `:` will output multiple `len(a)` times of the results, instead, indicating the index of each row will print the anticipated results.

Comment: I think this is the exactly the right and elegant way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 41):

Recent `numpy` versions have added a `take_along_axis` (and `put_along_axis`) that does this indexing cleanly.

```
In [101]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)                                                             
In [102]: b = np.array([1,0,2])                                                                        
In [103]: np.take_along_axis(a, b[:,None], axis=1)                                                     
Out[103]: 
array([[2],
       [4],
       [9]])
```

It operates in the same way as:

```
In [104]: a[np.arange(3), b]                                                                           
Out[104]: array([2, 4, 9])
```

but with different axis handling.  It's especially aimed at applying the results of `argsort` and `argmax`.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way might look like:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
   ...: [4, 5, 6],
   ...: [7, 8, 9]])

In [2]: y = [1, 0, 2]  #list of indices we want to select from matrix 'a'
```

`range(a.shape[0])` will return `array([0, 1, 2])`

```
In [3]: a[range(a.shape[0]), y] #we're selecting y indices from every row
Out[3]: array([2, 4, 9])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using iterator. Like this:

```
np.fromiter((row[index] for row, index in zip(X, Y)), dtype=int)
```

Time:

```
N = 1000
X = np.zeros(shape=(N, N))
Y = np.arange(N)

#@Aशwini चhaudhary
%timeit X[np.arange(len(X)), Y]
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.7 us per loop

#mine
%timeit np.fromiter((row[index] for row, index in zip(X, Y)), dtype=int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop

#mine
%timeit np.diag(X.T[Y])
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: OP mentioned it should run fast on *large* arrays, so your benchmarks are not very representative. I'm curious how your last method performs for (much) larger arrays!

Comment: @moarningsun: Updated. `np.diag(X.T[Y])` is so slow... But `np.diag(X.T)` is so fast(10us). I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from hpaulj using take_along_axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234228/2127374) should be the accepted one.

Here is a derived version with an N-dim index array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(20).reshape((2,2,5))
>>> idx = np.array([[1,0],[2,4]])
>>> np.take_along_axis(arr, idx[...,None], axis=-1)
array([[[ 1],
        [ 5]],

       [[12],
        [19]]])
```

Note that the selection operation is ignorant about the shapes. I used this to refine a possibly vector-valued `argmax` result from `histogram` by fitting parabolas:

```
def interpol(arr):
    i = np.argmax(arr, axis=-1)
    a = lambda Δ: np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(arr, i[...,None]+Δ, axis=-1), axis=-1)
    frac = .5*(a(1) - a(-1)) / (2*a(0) - a(-1) - a(1)) # |frac| < 0.5
    return i + frac
```

Note the `squeeze` to remove the dimension of size 1 resulting in the same shape of `i` and `frac`, the integer and fractional part of the peak position.

I'm quite sure that it is possible to avoid the `lambda`, but would the interpolation formula still look nice?

Answer (score 0):

Another clever way is to first transpose the array and index it thereafter. Finally, take the diagonal, its always the right answer.

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
Y = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2])

np.diag(X.T[Y])
```

**Step by step:**

Original arrays:

```
>>> X
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

>>> Y
array([1, 0, 2, 2])
```

Transpose to make it possible to index it right.

```
>>> X.T
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

Get rows in the Y order.

```
>>> X.T[Y]
array([[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

The diagonal should now become clear.

```
>>> np.diag(X.T[Y])
array([ 2,  4,  9, 12]
```

Comment: This technically works and looks very elegant. However, I find that this approach completely explodes when you’re dealing with large arrays. In my case, NumPy swallowed 30GB of swap and filled my SSD. I recommend using the advanced indexing approach instead.