# numpy: how to get a max from an argmax result

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I have a numpy array of arbitrary shape, e.g.:

```
a = array([[[ 1,  2],
            [ 3,  4],
            [ 8,  6]],

          [[ 7,  8],
           [ 9,  8],
           [ 3, 12]]])
a.shape = (2, 3, 2)
```

and a result of argmax over the last axis:

```
np.argmax(a, axis=-1) = array([[1, 1, 0],
                               [1, 0, 1]])
```

I'd like to get max:

```
np.max(a, axis=-1) = array([[ 2,  4,  8],
                            [ 8,  9, 12]])
```

But without recalculating everything. I've tried:

```
a[np.arange(len(a)), np.argmax(a, axis=-1)]
```

But got:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3)
```

How to do it? Similar question for 2-d: [numpy 2d array max/argmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584157/numpy-2d-array-max-argmax)

Comment: What is reshaped_x?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `a`. Correcting now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`advanced indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 8,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8],
        [ 9,  8],
        [ 3, 12]]])

In [18]: idx = a.argmax(axis=-1)

In [19]: m,n = a.shape[:2]

In [20]: a[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n),idx]
Out[20]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  8],
       [ 8,  9, 12]])
```

For a generic ndarray case of any number of dimensions, as stated in the [`comments by @hpaulj`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357335/numpy-how-to-get-a-max-from-an-argmax-result#comment67972075_40357693), we could use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), like so -

```
shp = np.array(a.shape)
dim_idx = list(np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in shp[:-1]]))
dim_idx.append(idx)
out = a[dim_idx]
```

Comment: Ok, but how to do it with an array of arbitrary shape and not exactly 3 dimensions?

Comment: Generate the first dimensions with `np.xi_` and tuple concatenate `idx`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, that should do it! Updated the post with that.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a typo somewhere? It seems `dims` are not used.

Comment: @sygi Sorry, was trying out few stuffs and in the end that wasn't required. Removed that line.

Comment: The FutureWarning says we want tuple 
`a[tuple([*np.ix_(*[np.arange(i) for i in a.shape[:-1]]), idxs])]`

Answer (score 0):

For ndarray with arbitrary shape, you can flatten the argmax indices, then recover the correct shape, as so:

```
idx = np.argmax(a, axis=-1)
flat_idx = np.arange(a.size, step=a.shape[-1]) + idx.ravel()
maximum = a.ravel()[flat_idx].reshape(*a.shape[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary-shape arrays, the following should work :)

```
a = np.arange(5 * 4 * 3).reshape((5,4,3))

# for last axis
argmax = a.argmax(axis=-1)
a[tuple(np.indices(a.shape[:-1])) + (argmax,)]

# for other axis (eg. axis=1)
argmax = a.argmax(axis=1)
idx = list(np.indices(a.shape[:1]+a.shape[2:]))
idx[1:1] = [argmax]
a[tuple(idx)]
```

or

```
a = np.arange(5 * 4 * 3).reshape((5,4,3))

argmax = a.argmax(axis=0)
np.choose(argmax, np.moveaxis(a, 0, 0))

argmax = a.argmax(axis=1)
np.choose(argmax, np.moveaxis(a, 1, 0))

argmax = a.argmax(axis=2)
np.choose(argmax, np.moveaxis(a, 2, 0))

argmax = a.argmax(axis=-1)
np.choose(argmax, np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0))
```