# return different values from different columns according to conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

a snapshot of DF looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

```
idf=pd.DataFrame({'p1': {549: 'Staffordshire_bullterrier', 1374: 'kelpie', 641: 'Samoyed'},
 'p1_conf': {549: 0.6892590000000001, 1374: 0.519047, 641: 0.362596},
 'p1_dog': {549: True, 1374: True, 641: True},
 'p2': {549: 'Norwegian_elkhound', 1374: 'German_shepherd', 641: 'Eskimo_dog'},
 'p2_conf': {549: 0.026121, 1374: 0.296069, 641: 0.245395},
 'p2_dog': {549: True, 1374: True, 641: True},
 'p3': {549: 'American_Staffordshire_terrier',
  1374: 'dingo',
  641: 'Siberian_husky'},
 'p3_conf': {549: 0.0230747, 1374: 0.0610053, 641: 0.108232},
 'p3_dog': {549: True, 1374: False, 641: True},
 'breed': {549: 'Staffordshire_bullterrier', 1374: 'kelpie', 641: 'Samoyed'}})
```

my goal is to return the most confidient breed. for example: if p1_dog is true then p1 should be returned. if not ture, the second most confident one is p2_dog, then p2 should be returned, etc. of course i can write something like this:

```
idf['breed']=idf.query("p1_dog==1").p1
idf['breed']=idf['breed'].fillna(idf.query("p1_dog==0 and p2_dog==1").p2)
idf['breed']=idf['breed'].fillna(idf.query("p1_dog==0 and p2_dog==0 and p3_dog==1").p3)
```

expecting result is the last column 'breed', which my code above can serve the purpose.
but i think it repetitive and not dry. what if i have hundreds of predictions? what's the best solution of this? thank you ahead!

Comment: kindly share data,not pics. [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also, post expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy sorry, i post the expected result, but truth to be told, i am not really sure how to mock this df...

Comment: try df.head().to_dict() and post the dictionary or pandas to clipboard. the guide i posted in  the previous comment should help. others might have better suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me a perfect case for `np.select`

## `np.select`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

condlist = [df["p1_dog"]==1,
            ((df["p1_dog"]==0) & (df["p2_dog"]==1)),
            ((df["p1_dog"]==0) & (df["p2_dog"]==0) & (df["p3_dog"]==1))]

choicelist = [df["p1"], df["p2"], df["p3"]]

df["breed"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

## Update: Generalization

There is a slightly more generic solution in particular when you have many columns to compare. It makes use of `np.argmax` and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435843/4819376)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"p1":['Staffordshire_bullterrier', 'Samoyed', 'kelpie','dingo'],
     "p1_dog":[True, False, False, True],
     "p2": ['Norwegian_elkhound', 'Eskimo_dog', 'German_shepherd', 'kelpie'],
     "p2_dog":[False, True, False, True],
     "p3":['American_Staffordshire_terrier', 'Siberian_husky', 'dingo','Samoyed'],
     "p3_dog":[False, True, True, True]
     })
```

We first select the first true in each row

```py
sel = df[["p1_dog", "p2_dog", "p3_dog"]].values.argmax(1)
```

Then we extract the matrix with breed names

```py
mat = df[["p1", "p2", "p3"]].values
```

And we finally define the breed using your logic

```py
df["breed"] = mat[np.arange(mat.shape[0]), sel]
```

Comment: it's indeed a good one, i didn't know this method. im gonna wait few more days to see if any better option pops up. thanks anyway

Comment: @victorlifan I added a solution which works in case you have many columns to compare. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

For each row in dataframe find name of column with maximum value

```
x = idf[['p1_conf','p2_conf','p3_conf']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Get number of column before the column name from x

```
breed_col = [idf.columns.get_loc(x.iloc[i])-1 for i in range(0, 3)]
```

Extract value of cell corresponding to the row and column: i and breed_col[i]

```
breed2 = []
for i in range(0,3):
    breed2.append(idf.iloc[i,breed_col[i]]) 

breed2_df = pd.DataFrame(breed2, columns = ['breed2'])
```

Reset indexes to enable concatentation of dataframes

```
idf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
pd.concat([idf, breed2_df], axis=1)
```