# Extract elements from a list of lists based on a list of indices for each list

Tags: python

I want to extract from this nested list:

```
[['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
 ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'], 
 ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]
```

the items by the indices for each row:

```
[2, 1, 4, 0]
```

The expected output will be:

```
['e', 'b', 'r', 't']
```

How can I do it?

Comment: its a method for caesar cypher. i cant do that. every list its one separate part of the decryption

Comment: @Geo If it's a caesar cypher there's a much better method of doing this. You just need to apply the letter offsets and mod 26.

Comment: @Moosefeather i searched the net, and i told that same thing to my professor. but he insisted in this method. perhaps for teaching purposes. but i agree, its not the best intuitive method, even for teaching a beginner like me

Comment: See [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Same question but for NumPy: [NumPy selecting specific column index per row by using a list of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23435782/7851470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
lst = [['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
       ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'], 
       ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]

indexes = [2, 1, 4, 0]
output = [sublst[index] for sublst, index in zip(lst, indexes)]
```