# NumPy selecting specific column ranges per row by using a list of indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

Say I have the following matrix:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5 ,6, 7]
[8, 9, 10,11]
```

So in this example, the column width we desire is 2. and the array size is 3x4. Is there a non loop way of obtaining a desired particular range of columns for each row?
Example I want values from columns [2,3] for row 1, [1,2] for row 2 and [0,1] for row 3.

So desired output is :

```
[3,4]
[5,6]
[8,9]
```

It would be desirable for the proposed solution to scale to arbitrarily large arrays and larger columns widths.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435782/numpy-selecting-specific-column-index-per-row-by-using-a-list-of-indexes) was asked here, however, here the person was just looking for a particular column index not a range of column indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [368]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
In [369]: idx = np.array([[2,3],[1,2],[0,1]])
In [370]: idx.shape
Out[370]: (3, 2)
```

Index rows with (3,1), which will broadcast with the (3,2) idx to give:

```
In [371]: arr[np.arange(3)[:,None], idx]
Out[371]: 
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [372]: arr
Out[372]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Don't have enough rep points to upvote the post- but the solution works! Thank you!