# Numpy: How to select row entries in a 2d array by column vector

Tags: numpy, indexing

How can I retrieve a column vector from a 2d array given an indicator column vector?

Suppose I have

```
X = np.array([[1, 4, 6],
              [8, 2, 9],
              [0, 3, 7],
              [6, 5, 1]])
```

and

```
S = np.array([0, 2, 1, 2])
```

Is there an elegant way to get from `X` and `S` the result `array([1, 9, 3, 1])`, which is equivalent to

```
np.array([x[s] for x, s in zip(X, S)])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy selecting specific column index per row by using a list of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435782/numpy-selecting-specific-column-index-per-row-by-using-a-list-of-indexes)

Comment: Yes it does, my search did not return that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(X, S[..., None], axis=1)
array([[1],
       [9],
       [3],
       [1]])
```

You need to make sure both array arguments are of the same shape (or broadcasting can be applied), hence the `S[..., None]` broadcasting.

Of course your can reshape the returned value with a `[:, 0]` slice.

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(X, S[..., None], axis=1)[:, 0]
array([1, 9, 3, 1])
```

---

Alternatively you can just use indexing with an arangement:

```
>>> X[np.arange(len(S)), S[np.arange(len(S))]]
array([1, 9, 3, 1])
```

I believe this is also equivalent to `np.diag(X[:, S])` but with unnecessary copying...

Answer (score 1):

For 2d arrays

```py
# Mention row numbers as one list and S which is column number as other
X[[0, 1, 2, 3], S]
```

```py
# more general
X[np.indices(S.shape), S]
```

[indexing_basics](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; curiously `X[:, S]` does not work.

Comment: Yeah need to be careful around that https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html