# Pandas/Python: How to create new column based on values from other columns and apply extra condition to this new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to create a new column **BB** based on the below condition.

1. Create a new column **BB**, if the values in column **TGR1**  is 0, assign 0 to **BB** else,
2. The value in **TGR1** is not 0, look up the columns (**'1','2','3'**) that corresponds with the value in **TGR1** assign the value in that column(either **'1','2','3'**)  to the new column **BB**.

I was able to achieve the first step using

```
df.loc[df['TGR1'] == 0, 'BB'] = 0
```

I also tried to use **np.where** to come up with but I can figure out the right way to go about this.

```
df['BB'] = np.where(df.TGR1 == 0,0, df.columns == test.TGR1.value )
    
    

Dist    Track    EVENT_ID      Date       1      2        3   TGR1 TGR2
                            
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   1   0
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   2   1
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   0   2
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   3   1
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   2   2
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   1   2
```

Expected Output:

```
Dist    Track    EVENT_ID      Date       1      2        3   TGR1 TGR2    BB     
                            
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   1   0     34.00        
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   2   1     5.18     
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   0   2       0
311m    Cran    174331755   2020-10-19  34.00   5.18    19.10   3   1     19.10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [numpy advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
import numpy as np
# extract columns 1,2,3 into a numpy array with a zeros column stacked on the left
vals = np.column_stack((np.zeros(len(df)), df[list('123')]))

vals
array([[ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.  , 34.  ,  5.18, 19.1 ]])

# use TGR1 values as the column index to extract corresponding values
df['BB'] = vals[np.arange(len(df)), df.TGR1.values]

df
   Dist Track   EVENT_ID        Date     1     2     3  TGR1  TGR2     BB
0  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     1     0  34.00
1  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     2     1   5.18
2  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     0     2   0.00
3  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     3     1  19.10
4  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     2     2   5.18
5  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1     1     2  34.00
```

Comment: Thanks, @Psidom I accepted your answer because in terms of speed it is faster and can be scaled for multiple columns in a dataframe.

Comment: I get the below error when I tried the above function on my Dataframe

`IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: @ChukypedroOkolie it seems your TGR1 column is not of integer type, try convert it first. `vals[np.arange(len(df)), df.TGR1.values.astype(int)]`

Answer (score 4):

Here you can try to play some numpy trick as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234228/4819376).

We first define a matrix with values from columns 1,2 and 3 and add a first column with zeros.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# we first define a matrix 
# with len(df) rows and 4 columns
mat = np.zeros((len(df), 4))

# Then we fill the last 3 columns 
# with values from df
mat[:,1:] = df[["1", "2", "3"]].values

# Then a vector with values from df["TGR1"]
v = df["TGR1"].values


# Finally we take the given index
# from each row on matrix
df["BB"] = np.take_along_axis(mat, v[:,None], axis=1)
```

## Timing

I compared the timing for some of the answers here. I just took a `df` 10_000 larger than the original one

```py
df_bk = pd.concat([df for i in range(10_000)], ignore_index=True)
```

and before run each test I do `df =  df_bk.copy()`

### @wwnde's solution

```sh
CPU times: user 430 ms, sys: 12.1 ms, total: 442 ms
Wall time: 452 ms
```

### @cookesd's solution

```sh
CPU times: user 746 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 746 ms
Wall time: 746 ms
```

### @rpanai's solution

```sh
CPU times: user 5.54 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 5.54 ms
Wall time: 4.84 ms
```

### @Psidom's solution

```sh
CPU times: user 5.93 ms, sys: 141 µs, total: 6.07 ms
Wall time: 5.61 ms
```

Psidom's solution and mine have basically the same timing. Here is a plot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create the column using a list comprehension with your if-else logic

```
# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'TGR1':[random.randint(0,3) for i in range(10)],
                   '1':[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10)],
                   '2':[random.randint(101,200) for i in range(10)],
                   '3':[random.randint(201,300) for i in range(10)]})
# creating the column
df['BB'] = [0 if tgr1_val == 0 else df.loc[ind,str(tgr1_val)]
            for ind,tgr1_val in enumerate(df['TGR1'].values)]

df

#    TGR1   1    2    3   BB
# 0     0  54  107  217    0
# 1     2  71  128  277  128
# 2     1  25  103  269   25
# 3     0  80  112  279    0
# 4     2  98  167  228  167
# 5     3  26  192  285  285
# 6     0  27  107  228    0
# 7     2  13  103  298  103
# 8     3  28  196  289  289
# 9     2  72  186  251  186
```

Answer (score 1):

this is done easy with the use of boolean mask as you did it in your step one:

```
df['BB'][df['TGR1'] == 0] = 0
```

for the other values greaters than 0:

```
df['BB'][df['TGR1'] == 1] = df['1'][df['TGR1'] == 1]
df['BB'][df['TGR1'] == 2] = df['2'][df['TGR1'] == 2]
df['BB'][df['TGR1'] == 3] = df['3'][df['TGR1'] == 3]

output:
    1         2       3   TGR1   BB
0   34.0    5.18    19.1    1   34.00
1   34.0    5.18    19.1    2   5.18
2   34.0    5.18    19.1    0   0.00
3   34.0    5.18    19.1    3   19.10
4   34.0    5.18    19.1    2   5.18
```

probably it is pretty much readable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with it in terms of readability but it gets longer as the number of columns `('1','2','3')` grows.

Answer (score 0):

Drop TGR2temporarily, do alook up of columns using TGR1 and that should do. code below

```py
s = df.astype(str).drop('TGR2',1).filter(regex='\d', axis=1).reset_index()#Drop TRG2 and filter rows with digits to allow lookup
i = s.astype(str).columns.get_indexer(s.TGR1)#DO alook up to get columns whose values are in TGR1
df['BB'] = s.values[s.index,i]
```

```
   Dist Track   EVENT_ID        Date     1     2     3 TGR1 TGR2    BB
0  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    1    0  34.0
1  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    2    1  5.18
2  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    0    2     0
3  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    3    1  19.1
4  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    2    2  5.18
5  311m  Cran  174331755  2020-10-19  34.0  5.18  19.1    1    2  34.0
```