# get value from tensor by using index array python

Tags: python, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have an array A :

```
A = [[1,  2  ,3  ,4],
     [5,  6  ,7  ,8],
     [9, 10 ,11 ,12],]
```

and I want to get the 2nd row in the 3rd element (i.e. '7') :

I can do it by:

```
A[1,2]
```

For the general dimension number I want to have something generic.
Given index list B=[1,2]
I want to have something like MATLAB indexing:

A[B] or A[*B]

The first gives 2 rows and the second results in an error.
How can I do this?

---

edit: type(A)=type(B)=np.array

Comment: Do we talk about standard Python 3 lists? Because both A[1, 2] and A[[1, 2]] is illegal and will cause `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` error. Or is it, for example, numpy's array?

Comment: np.array. thanks for the note. i'll clarify in the question

Comment: I found this (ugly) solution:
B = tuple( np.reshape(B,(1, len(B))))
and than:
A(B)
hoping for better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to unpack collection with "*" because numpy supports tuple indexing. You problem is that there is difference between indexing by list and by tuple. So,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
])

print("indexing by list:\n", A[[0, 1]], '\n')
# Output:
# indexing by list:
#   [[1 2 3 4]
#   [5 6 7 8]] 

print("indexing by tuple:\n", A[(0, 1)])
# Output:
# indexing by tuple:
#   2
```

Hope, it helps. [For the further reading](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) about numpy indexing.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, suppose you are interested in "[array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)", i.e., getting an array of values back of length `L`, where each value in the array is from a location in `A`. You would like to indicate these locations via an index of some kind.

Suppose `A` is `N`-dimensional. Array indexing solves this problem by letting you pass a tuple of `N` lists of length `L`.  The `i`th list gives the indices corresponding to the `i`th dimension in `A`.  In the simplest case, the index lists can be length-one (`L=1`):

```
>>> A[[1], [2]]
array([7])
```

But the index lists could be longer (`L=5`):

```
>>> A[[1,1,1,1,0], [2,2,2,2,0]]
array([7, 7, 7, 7, 1])
```

I emphasize that this is a tuple of lists; you can also go:

```
>>> first_axis, second_axis = [1,1,1,1,0], [2,2,2,2,0]
>>> A[(first_axis,second_axis)]
array([7, 7, 7, 7, 1])
```

You can also pass a non-tuple sequence (a list of lists rather than a tuple of lists) `A[[first_axis,second_axis]]` but in NumPy version 1.21.2, a `FutureWarning` is given noting that this is deprecated.

Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435869/4901005

Comment: thanks for the extention for several outputs. the question still stands. will you be able to index it like: A[(first_axis,second_axis)] and first_axis, second_axis = [1,1,1,1,0], [2,2,2,2,0]

Comment: Yes, I clarified that a tuple of lists is needed, and you can use list variables in your tuple.