# select the first N elements of each row in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to select the first two elements of each row in column a and column b.

Here is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A123', 'A567','A100'], 'b': ['A156', 'A266666','A35555']})

>>> df
      a        b
0  A123     A156
1  A567  A266666
2  A100   A35555
```

desired output

```
>>> df
      a      b
0     A1     A1
1     A5     A2
2     A1     A3
```

I have been trying to use `df.loc` but not been successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select One Element in Each Row of a Numpy Array by Column Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074422/select-one-element-in-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-by-column-indices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
In [905]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:2])
Out[905]:
    a   b
0  A1  A1
1  A5  A2
2  A1  A3
```

Or,

```
In [908]: df.applymap(lambda x: x[:2])
Out[908]:
    a   b
0  A1  A1
1  A5  A2
2  A1  A3
```

Comment: thanks for that it works well for me. if I decide to apply the same thing but only to one column (say column a). How can we do that?  I have tried  df.apply(lambda x: x['a'].str[:2]) and  df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.str[:2]) but it is not working

Comment: use `df['a'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])`

Comment: @Akshay Thank you for your answer which worked fine for my data unti i got this error TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' . Aftr investigation I found that the error is due to missing values in column a (some rows are empty) this is due to imperfect dataset. How can I tackle that error and tell python to ignore the error and get on with it?

Comment: You can write your own function to handle NaN and pass it to apply. But as error suggests I think one of your column is Float, try converting it into string and then apply.

Comment: the error does suggest that my column is not a string but it is definitely one (i have just double checked). The issue is coming from missing values because when I run the code and ignore those row with null/missing values  i get no error

Comment: Try this to handle Nulls `lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x) else x[:2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [107]: df.apply(lambda c: c.str.slice(stop=2))
Out[107]:
    a   b
0  A1  A1
1  A5  A2
2  A1  A3
```