# How to index columns with a computed array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Please have a look at this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

#1
X = [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5]]
c = [[0,0], [0,1], [0,3]]

#2
dists = distance.cdist(X, c)
print(dists)

#3
dmini = np.argmin(dists, axis=1)
print(dmini)

#4
mindists = dists[:, dmini]
print(mindists)
```

(#1) So I have my data `X`, some other points (centroids) `c`, then (#2) I compute the distance from each point in `X` to all the centroids `c`, and store the result in `dists`.

(#3) Then I select the index of the minimum distances with `argmin`.

(#4) Now I only want to select the value of the minimum values, using the indexes computed in step #3.

However, I get a strange output.

```
# dists
[[ 0.  1.  3.]
 [ 1.  0.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.]
 [ 3.  2.  0.]
 [ 4.  3.  1.]
 [ 5.  4.  2.]]
#dmini
[0 1 1 2 2 2]

#mindists
[[ 0.  1.  1.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 3.  2.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  3.  3.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 5.  4.  4.  2.  2.  2.]]
```

Reading here and there, it seems possible to select specific columns by giving a list of integers (indexes). In this case I should use the `dmini` values for indexing columns along rows.

I was expecting `mindists` to be `(6,)` in shape. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have [tag:python-3.x] (or 2.7) and [tag:numpy] too? (IIRC)

Comment: I do have those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select One Element in Each Row of a Numpy Array by Column Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074422/select-one-element-in-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-by-column-indices)

Comment: I have read the question and the answer. However, I cannot understand what's wrong with code above since if I write `dists[:, [1]]`, the second column is correctly selected. Is using `np.choose`, ore  more complex codes, the only way?

Comment: @AntonioSesto I can't understand what you mean. I can only see the tag [tag:python] in the question.

Comment: Now I understand. I will modify the tags. Thanks.