# Numpy arrays: row/column wise argmax with random ties

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, argmax

Here is what I am trying to do with Numpy in Python 2.7. Suppose I have an array `a` defined by the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,3,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,1]])
```

I can do `a.argmax(0)` or `a.argmax(1)` to get the row/column wise argmax:

```
a.argmax(0)
Out[329]: array([2, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
a.argmax(1)
Out[330]: array([1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

However, when there is a tie like in `a`'s first row, I would like to get the argmax decided randomly between the ties (by default, Numpy returns the first element whenever a tie occurs in argmax or argmin).

Last year, someone put a question on solving Numpy argmax/argmin ties randomly: [Select One Element in Each Row of a Numpy Array by Column Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074422/select-one-element-in-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-by-column-indices)

However, the question aimed at uni-dimensional arrays. There, the most voted answer works well for that. There is a second answer that attempts to solve the problem also for multidimensional arrays but doesn't work - i.e. it does not return, for each row/column the index of the maximum value with ties solved randomly.

What would be the most performent way to do that, since I am working with big arrays?

Comment: The linked SO doesn't seem relevant.  If you want 'most performent', you need to first give us a working example.  In order to claim my answer is better, I have to show that it gets the correct value, and runs faster.  To do that I'd rather not make up my own example(s) and base method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generic case solution to pick one per group

To solve a general case of picking a random number from a list/array of numbers that specify the ranges for the picks, we would use a trick of creating a uniform rand array, add offset specified by the interval lengths and then perform `argsort`. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def random_num_per_grp(L):
    # For each element in L pick a random number within range specified by it
    r1 = np.random.rand(np.sum(L)) + np.repeat(np.arange(len(L)),L)
    offset = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(L[:-1])]
    return r1.argsort()[offset] - offset
```

Sample case -

```
In [217]: L = [5,4,2]

In [218]: random_num_per_grp(L) # i.e. select one per [0-5,0-4,0-2]
Out[218]: array([2, 0, 1])
```

So, the output would have same number of elements as in input `L` and the first output element would be in `[0,5)`, second in `[0,4)` and so on.

---

#### Solving our problem here

To solve our case here, we would use a modified version (specifically remove the offset removal part at the end of the func, like so -

```
def random_num_per_grp_cumsumed(L):
    # For each element in L pick a random number within range specified by it
    # The final output would be a cumsumed one for use with indexing, etc.
    r1 = np.random.rand(np.sum(L)) + np.repeat(np.arange(len(L)),L)
    offset = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(L[:-1])]
    return r1.argsort()[offset]
```

**Approach #1**

One solution could use it like so -

```
def argmax_per_row_randtie(a):
    max_mask = a==a.max(1,keepdims=1)
    m,n = a.shape
    all_argmax_idx = np.flatnonzero(max_mask)
    offset = np.arange(m)*n
    return all_argmax_idx[random_num_per_grp_cumsumed(max_mask.sum(1))] - offset
```

**Verification**

Let's test out on the given sample with a huge number of runs and count number of occurences for each index for each row

```
In [235]: a
Out[235]: 
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 1]])

In [225]: all_out = np.array([argmax_per_row_randtie(a) for i in range(10000)])

# The first element (row=0) should have similar probabilities for 1 and 2
In [236]: (all_out[:,0]==1).mean()
Out[236]: 0.504

In [237]: (all_out[:,0]==2).mean()
Out[237]: 0.496

# The second element (row=1) should only have 2
In [238]: (all_out[:,1]==2).mean()
Out[238]: 1.0

# The third element (row=2) should only have 1
In [239]: (all_out[:,2]==1).mean()
Out[239]: 1.0
```

**Approach #2 : Use `masking` for performance**

We could make use of `masking` and hence avoid that `flatnonzero` with the intention of gaining performance as working with boolean arrays generally is. Also, we would generalize to cover both rows (axis=1) and columns(axis=0) to give ourselves a modified one, like so -

```
def argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=1): 
    max_mask = a==a.max(axis=axis,keepdims=True)
    m,n = a.shape
    L = max_mask.sum(axis=axis)
    set_mask = np.zeros(L.sum(), dtype=bool)
    select_idx = random_num_per_grp_cumsumed(L)
    set_mask[select_idx] = True
    if axis==0:
        max_mask.T[max_mask.T] = set_mask
    else:
        max_mask[max_mask] = set_mask
    return max_mask.argmax(axis=axis)
```

Sample runs on `axis=0` and `axis=1` -

```
In [423]: a
Out[423]: 
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 1]])
In [424]: argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=1)
Out[424]: array([1, 2, 1])

In [425]: argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=1)
Out[425]: array([2, 2, 1])

In [426]: a[1,1] = 8

In [427]: a
Out[427]: 
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [4, 8, 6],
       [7, 8, 1]])

In [428]: argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=0)
Out[428]: array([2, 1, 1])

In [429]: argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=0)
Out[429]: array([2, 1, 1])

In [430]: argmax_randtie_masking_generic(a, axis=0)
Out[430]: array([2, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way is to add a small random number to all the values at the start, so your data would be like this:

```
a = np.array([[1.1827,3.1734,3.9187],[4.8172,5.7101,6.9182],[7.1834,8.5012,1.9818]])
```

That can be done by `a = a + np.random.random(a.shape)`.

If you later need to get the original values back, you can do `a.astype(int)` to drop the fractional parts.

Comment: You would have to guarantee that the number added is less than the smallest difference between a maximum number and the next largest (if the inputs are integers this works fine).  Still, this is a clever answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of random numbers, the same shape as your input, but mask out the array to only leave the candidates for selection.

```
import numpy as np

def rndArgMax(a, axis):
    a_max = a.max(axis, keepdims=True)
    tmp = np.random.random(a.shape) * (a == a_max)
    return tmp.argmax(axis)

a = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(2, 3, 4))
print(rndArgMax(a, 1))
# array([[1, 1, 2, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```