# Is there a more efficient way of encoding every row than using a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, vectorization

**What I'm attempting**

I have a dataset where every row is a team of 11 players, with each player represented by their shirt number. For example, Team A may comprise of `[1, 66, 22, 4, 26, 3, 18, 8, 9, 11, 10]`. The possible shirt numbers range from 0 to 99, and I would like to then represent the teams with a vector of size 100 where indices corresponding to the shirt numbers are marked by 1s, and the others by 0s. Team A, for instance, would then be:

```
[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

**What I've tried**

I've implemented this transformation with a simple function:

```
def encode_lineup(kit_numbers, squad_size=100):
    encoded_lineup = np.zeros(squad_size)
    encoded_lineup[kit_numbers] = 1
    return encoded_lineup
```

Now in trying to extend this implementation to multiple teams (an array of teams), I have not been able to come up with anything better than a loop like:

```
all_encoded_lineups = np.zeros(number_of_teams, squad_size)

for i in range(number_of_teams):
    all_encoded_lineups[i] = encode_lineup(teams[i], squad_size)
```

**What I need help with**

I would like to do this more efficiently if possible - do you know have any suggestions towards vectorizing this implementation, or any other ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the [`put` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html?highlight=put#numpy.put):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
replace_with_value = -1
replace_at_indices = [1, 4]
np.put(a, replace_at_indices, replace_with_value)
print(a)
'''                                                                                                                                                                              
[1 -1 3 4 -1]                                                                                                                                                                    
'''
```

Your logic (whatever it is) would create a vector of indices where you replace zeros with something else.

To extend this to multidimensional arrays, you could `flatten`, `put`, and `reshape`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100703/19410